# Found a branding project, but can someone tell me what exactly these numbers below represent? (see image>>)

Tags: typography, terminology, branding

[image]

I was just curious to see if anyone could tell me what the numbers below the wordmark are meant to indicate? Kerning?

Comment: It'd really help if you made them darker and removed the extra space

Comment: You would need to ask the design or company what they mean. There's no inherent meaning to them. (I suppose they *could* be kerning values.. but that's a wild guess).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this could be from a style guide.  My guess is this is in reference to the kerning between the indicated letters based on the fact that most typefaces aren't designed to have the capital "W" to hang over the next letter.

[image]

Comment: I totally agree, however "-3" within a kerning pair is almost negligible and I don't think it would ever result in the /W/ to hang over the /o/.

I really appreciate the reply tho! I only asked this for my own curiosity.